# delete song from redux state within reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm learning `react-redux`, I have a very simple application which displays dummy songs from a static list, my current reducers look like the following:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

var songs = [
 { title: "No Scrubs", duration: "4:05" },
 { title: "Song 2", duration: "3:55" },
 { title: "Song 3", duration: "2:23" },
 { title: "Song 4", duration: "1:75" },
];

const songsReducer = () => {
  return songs;
};

const selectedSongReducer = (selectedSong = null, action) => {
  if (action.type === "SONG_SELECTED") {
    return action.payload;
  }

  return selectedSong;
};

const deleteSongReducer = (selectedSong = null, action) => {
  console.log("delete called");
  if (action.type === "SONG_DELETED") {

    var newArray = songs.filter((item) => item !== action.payload);
    console.log(newArray);
    return newArray;
  }
  return selectedSong;
};

export default combineReducers({
  songs: songsReducer,
  selectedSong: selectedSongReducer,
  deleteSong: deleteSongReducer,
});
```

the selectedSongReducer is working as expected, however, I'm trying to remove a song from the static list when calling deleteSongReducer I can see a new array in the console when logging it, yet the results are reflected within the UI and by that I mean the deleted song is not removed from the list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going at this with a non complete mindset about how the reducers should work. You need the delete action to be handled inside the songs reducer, not just some other reducer.

A reducer represents a part of the state of your application, such as songs, and handles all actions that should have an effect on that part. In simple terms, your `songsReducer` should handle:

1. initial state
2. adding songs
3. removing songs
4. reordering songs
5. any other action that could touch the array of songs

```
function songsReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SONG_DELETED':
      return state.filter((item) => item !== action.payload);
    case 'SONG_ADDED':
      return ...;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

the `selectedSong` can stay in another reducer, because it represents a different part of your state - not the list of songs but a pointer to which song is selected - and that is fine.

Comment: yeah I'm still trying to get my head around the react-redux side of things, however, what you have written makes sense now, I did have to change the default return to "songs" to get it all working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

can you check how many time your Console.log(song) in UI render ?  after deleteSongReducer action performed , if its rendring two times then might be reducer resetting to its initialState.. although if you can share a codePen I can look deeper to it